# Passing List from .razor.cs file to the main razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I am creating an upload/download site with blazor, and in my project. I have an index.razor file and an Index.Razor.cs file where I am putting my Index model which references the dbcontext etc. (see code below)

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    private readonly UploadFileContext _context;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, UploadFileContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<PdfFile> Files { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Files = _context.Files.ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDownloadAsync(int? id)
    {
        var myInv = await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (myInv == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (myInv.Attachment == null)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] byteArr = myInv.Attachment;
            string mimeType = "application/pdf";
            return new FileContentResult(byteArr, mimeType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = $"{myInv.FileType} {myInv.Number}.pdf"
            };
        }

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int? id)
    {
        var myInv = await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (myInv == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (myInv.Attachment == null)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            myInv.Attachment = null;
            _context.Update(myInv);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        Files = await _context.Files.ToListAsync();
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I am trying to reference my ilist in the main razor page which I will use in a foreach loop, to display the name and filetype of each file.

How can I do this?

Comment: You're not on separate files. `razor.cs` contains code for the `.razor` component. It's the same class.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that, which is why im wondering when i try to reference the  iList in my foreach - that it says it doesnt exist.

Comment: What you posted isn't a Blazor class at all. It's a Razor Page that runs on the *server*. Blazor pages are actually *components* with a `@page` directive. Perhaps you should start with the Blazor WebAssembly Hosted template to see what goes into Blazor and what runs as a controller on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define foreach loop with `Files` in Razor page.

```
@if (Files.Count > 0)  
{
     <ol>
     @foreach (var file in Files)
     {      
        <li>@file.Name</li>
        <li>@file.FileType</li>          
     }
     </ol>
 }
```